# tensorflow contrib.learn save

Tags: save, tensorflow, skflow

How do you save your model output with the new contrib.learn functions like contrib.learn.DNNClassifier?

The deprecated functions like skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier had methods .save and .restore.  These were supposedly migrated over to the contrib.learn functions, but there are no longer save and restore methods that I can find.

If you create the variables specifically, you can use  tf.train.Saver, but is there any way to save your graph, weights, and biases if you just use the contrib.learn.DNNClassifier or contrib.learn.DNNRegressor functions?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you come to a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Variables are saved from `fit()`, and restored at the beginning of `fit()`, `evaluate()`, and `predict()`.

Do you have a use case where you need to save or restore variables outside of the context of those 3 calls?

Answer (score 0):

#### When training

You call `DNNClassifier(..., model_dir)` and then call the `fit()` and `evaluate()` method.

#### When testing

You call `DNNClassifier(..., model_dir)` and then can call `predict()` methods. **Your model will find a trained model in the `model_dir` and will load the trained model params.**

#### Reference

[Issue #3340 of TF](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3340)